# How can I remove unwanted cropped pages from Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, crop

Executing the crop command in Acrobat from a 3000pt * 2000pt document to 1500pt*1800pt only hides the document outside of the new boundaries but the original document still remains without change; if anyone uses the touch-up tool and moves the content, all "hidden" information outside the cropped page may appear again by dragging it into view. The page acting as a window (or a mask) to display the 3000pt * 2000pt.

I am wondering if there is a solution to crop permanently the document without reprinting it again into PDF file?

Please find pictures attached:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some research i figure out the best way to solve this issue.

in Acrobat X:

there are two solutions

First Solution:

file > action wizard > [prepare for web publishing] or [publish sensitive documents]
click next in the opened dialogged box
in remove hidden information dialog box check "deleted or cropped content"
Second Solution

select from the right panels the panel called "Protection"
select choose to remove hidden information or you can do redaction to any page you want.
acrobat will examine the whole document for any hidden information and the result will appear in a left panel
after the examination click remove.
for more information how to remove hidden information please follow the following link http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/pdf-redaction.html

Answer (score 0):

No, since Acrobat does not support destructive cropping - all you're doing as you say is resizing the 'viewable content'. Therefore you can at any time change the cropping, including removing it to restore the original page.